# Retrieve Firestore sub collection

Tags: angular, typescript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I have the following Firestore structure:

```
case (col)

----someFirestoreId (doc | Do I need a specific ID?)
-------------------name (field)
-------------------id (field)
-------------------modules (col)
--------------------------0 (doc)
--------------------------1 (doc)
--------------------------2 (doc)


----someFirestoreId (doc | Do I need a specific ID?)
-------------------name (field)
-------------------id (field)
-------------------modules (col)
--------------------------0 (doc)
--------------------------1 (doc)

(0 & 1 each have its own fields)
```

How can I retrieve this data?

Preferentially I want an array that holds each case with its sub collection `modules` and its docs, but since I assume that this isn't possible - is there a special approach to retrieve this kind of data?

**In the end I need to be able to get the case id from a parameter route and display the allocated modules, by iterating through the modules' docs `0, 1, 2...`**

**Edit:**
That's what I've got so far:

```
this.db.collection('test').valueChanges()
  .subscribe(val => {
    this.casesService.cases = val;
    this.casesService.animate = true;
    for (let i = 0; i < val.length; i++) {
      this.db.collection('test').doc(val[i].name).collection('modules').valueChanges()
        .subscribe(value => {
          console.log(value);
          this.casesService.case = value;
          resolve(true);
        });
      }
  });
```

This one is iterating through all cases, gets the modules and saves inside of `caseService`. That way I have an array `case` with its docs `0, 1, 2...`


But in case of multiple entries, `case` will be overwritten with every new case. Additionally `case` is not allocated to any case inside of `cases` entry.

All `cases`/entries are being displayed in portfolio - when a case is clicked I get its data like this:

```
this.route.paramMap.pipe(
      map(paramMap => +paramMap.get('id')),
    switchMap((id: number) => this.caseService.getCase(id)),
    ).subscribe(cases => { this.case = cases;
});
```

That's where I need the allocated modules `0, 1, 2...` 

Furthermore this approach requires the case collection name to be a normal name, which might be a downside as well.

Comment: What have you tried and where are you facing the issue in your code?

Comment: @AJT_82 I've tried it, it kind of worked but only statically. I need it to be dynamic. All I did so far, was going through the collections and docs with their static names as paths. In the end I had an array for only one case with its modules - obviously this won't work for other cases since it's dynamic. That's where I'm stuck.

Comment: You need to show us your code and exlplain where you are facing your issue :)

Comment: @AJT_82 The edit might be a little confusing, but I tried my best.